# Prevent HDD to power up

Tags: hard-disk, udev

OS installed on SSD. Some rarely accessed files are on HDD.
How do I prevent HDD to power on (spin up) and then to mount it manually as needed?

Tried udev rule
`SUBSYSTEM=="sda", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0"`
didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/852727/safe-to-manually-spin-down-hard-drive-with-hdparm).

Comment: @doneal24 similar, not duplicate. I can spin HDD down manually, but then anything like smartmontools can wake it up. HDD has to be "off" from boot time

Comment: do you happen to have an entry in your /etc/fstab for your SSD? Because in general, automatic mounting doesn't happen for internal drives unless explicitly user-requested.

Comment: For smartd you can use `-n standby,q` option. For `mount` (scanning for UUIDs) you can put `/dev/disk/by-uuid/X` instead of `UUID=x`. Unfortunately that does not solve everything else... there are too many things that wake up drives and the number is growing. People use all SSD storage these days and nobody cares about HDD standby anymore. Best you can do is pull the plug...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Forgot to mention, I'm on Ubuntu - many thing automated. There is entry for SSD in /etc/fstab, but not for HDD

Comment: @frostschutz True. Guess I'll make my peace with `hdparm spindown_time` set short and forget about this